# Dealing with "mostly static" content in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My current project has some dynamic stuff but also has quite a few of these "mostly static" pages. These are pages that need to be updated CMS style, like the "about" page or the "welcome" page, but only rarely.

My end goal is to have the site owner able to log in and edit the text of these pages. There will be multiple translations of these various pages.

What is the best way to deal with these "mostly static" pages?

My current thinking is that I will need to create a model for the organization and store the "about" blurb and other info as properties of that model. Then I can translate using globalize2. It seems goofy since there will only ever be one of these models.

Does that seem reasonable?

Anyone have a better idea?